# How to define object inside sealed generic hierarchy?

Tags: kotlin

How to define object inside sealed generic hierarchy? The object declaration doesn't work with generics.

```
sealed class PaginationViewState<T> {
    object LoadingFirstPage: PaginationViewState<T>()//doesn't work
    object LoadingPage: PaginationViewState<T>()//doesn't work

    data class DataLoaded<T>(val data: List<T>): PaginationViewState<T>()
    data class DataLoadedFromCache<T>(val data: List<T>): PaginationViewState<T>()
    data class Failure<T>(val e: Throwable): PaginationViewState<T>()
}
```

Comment: It does work. You aren't specifying what `T` should be, instead passing `T` as a type which doesn't exist. Try a type instead.

Comment: As `T` is the type of data that the view state holds, I think the correct solution for you here is to make `LoadingFirstPage` and `LoadingPage` classes instead of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, since an `object` is a singleton, it cannot inherit a generic class without supplying a *concrete type* for the type argument.

You can only define an `object` replacing `T` with some type:

```
sealed class PaginationViewState<T> {
    object LoadingFirstPage: PaginationViewState<Any>()

    //...
}
```

If what you want is to be able to use the object in place of `PaginationViewState<T>` with *any possible* `T`, then you can use the [generics variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), with either `class PaginationViewState<out T>` and `object ...: PaginationViewState<Nothing>` or `class PaginationViewState<in T>` and `object ...: PaginationViewState<Any>` (but that limits the positions where `T` can appear in the class), or use the star-projection where you want to use the objects: e.g. make a function accept `PaginationViewState<*>`, and then an object with any `T` can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It won't work in my case though since I can't define a class with desired type `PaginationViewState<AdModel> =PaginationViewState.LoadingFirstPage`. I'll stick with regular classes for now.